# Why is XCode 4 compiling ~ 3000 XIBs when I only have ~ 200?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, localization, xib

I am working on an app that has 12 localizations of about 16 XIBs.

XCode 4, after a clean and rebuild, says it is compiling 2704 XIBs!

The build log shows that XCode is compiling the same XIB many times for each localization.

Anyone know why this would be?

Note that everything works fine in the app -- this doesn't seem to have any effect as you'd imagine. But it's just wasting my time! :-)

status:

[image]

log:

[image]

project navigator excerpt:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I have encountered this XCode issue too. I don't know how to stop XCode adding xib files multiple times, but there is a workaround to shorten your project build time: you should go to the current target's **Build Phases** tab and remove all duplicated xibs in **Copy Bundle Resources** stage, leaving the only copy for each one.

To make my answer more clear:

Inside the **Copy Bundle Resources** list you should leave only the *one* item for each individual xib file, in spite of number of languages you have. Something similar to:

[image: screen]

Comment: Thanks. I see the correct number of XIB files in the Copy Bundle Resources phase with a location in light gray of "in (localization).lproj". This makes me think that that part is fine. Indeed, it says "Copy Bundle Resources (405 items)" not ~3000 items.

Comment: @z8000 Could you please attach a screenshot of Copy Bundle Resources?

Comment: @z8000 And how many items of *"MyFile.xib  in (localization).lproj"* do you see in Copy Bundle Resources for a single MyFile.xib? There should be exactly one, not for each language.

Comment: oh I have the 16 instances of each. But I cannot seem to delete them from Copy Bundle Resources! Hitting 'delete', 'cmd-delete', or the '-' button at the bottom does nothing.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense to me too. If there's an XCode bug wherein it expects one MyFile.xib in Copy Bundle Resources, it would thus process all the localizations for that file (M). So if that file is listed N times (the bug), it's going to process that file N * M times.

Comment: @z8000 There's another issue of XCode, you actually delete them, but they are not disappearing from the list. Close and reopen your build settings view to refresh that list.